# I have want to getinent outside the oncreate() activity to extract my YouTube link in exoplayer from another class

Tags: java, android

From my recyclerview adapter class through intent put extra I am passing the URL of the video and I want to getintent outside the oncreate() activity.to pass the URL in another string which is outside my oncreate(). is there is any possibility to access getintent string outside the oncreate?

in this class I want to getintent of video URL before the ONCREATE() to pass the URL instead of static URL;

```
package com.example.movies.uis;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.movies.R;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;

import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.Format;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.VideoMeta;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YtFile;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private String GRID_YOUTUBE_ID = "s9-Id1WJQyo";
    private String BASE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com";
    private String youtubeLink = BASE_URL + "/watch?v=" + GRID_YOUTUBE_ID;
//hello


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        extractYoutubeUrl();
        simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player);
        
        
        String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        String urlYoutube = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videourl");
        
        
        TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        tv_name.setText(title);





    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void extractYoutubeUrl() {
        new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> sparseArray, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                //Log.d("======>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "onExtractionComplete: "+ytFiles.toString());
                if (sparseArray != null) {
                    for(int i=0, size = sparseArray.size(); i < size; i++){
                        YtFile ytFile = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                        Format frmt = ytFile.getFormat();
                        if(frmt.getExt() == "mp4" || frmt.getExt() == "webm"){
                          //  Log.d(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "index: " + i+ " path: "+ytFile);
                        }


                        playVideo(ytFile.getUrl());


                    }

                }

            }
        }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
    }

    public void playVideo(String downloadUrl) {

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(ExoPlayerCustomise.getSharedInstance(PlayerActivity.this).getSimpleExoPlayerView().getPlayer());

        ExoPlayerCustomise.getSharedInstance(PlayerActivity.this).playStream(downloadUrl);
    }






}
```

and here is my adapter class code which is passing the URL to the activity
onclick item

```
         public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerviewAdpaterFragment70s.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        
                Context context = holder.cardthumnail.getContext();
                Songsapis songs = songsapis.get(position);
                holder.cardtitle.setText(songs.getTitle());
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(songs.getThumbnail())
                            .into(holder.cardthumnail);
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
                            Intent i = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("title",songsapis.get(position).getTitle());
                            i.putExtra("videourl",songsapis.get(position).getUrl());
                            context.startActivity(i);
        
        
        
        
                        }
                    });
        
            }
```

Comment: You can call getIntent in any function of an Activity.  There's nothing magic about it, its just a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use deeplink with specific structure

Append blew line manifest

Define ACTION_VIEW intent action so that the intent filter can be reached from Google Search

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

And add BROWSABLE category in order to be accessible from a out off app

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Add your link structure

```
<data android:host="youtube" android:pathPattern=".*" android:scheme="https"/>
```

Get data with intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

Send data to app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://youtube"));
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make String title and urlYoutube global( i.e. outside onCreate). and then Initialize both inside onCreate by this way you can use intent data outside onCreate method

for example

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private String GRID_YOUTUBE_ID = "s9-Id1WJQyo";
    private String BASE_URL = "https://www.youtube.com";
    private String youtubeLink = BASE_URL + "/watch?v=" + GRID_YOUTUBE_ID;
    public String title,urlYoutube; 
//hello


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        extractYoutubeUrl();
        simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player);


        title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        urlYoutube = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videourl");


    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.